# How to convert int into Uint32 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, type-conversion, int, uint32

Is there a way to convert an integer into the format Uint32.

```
int x = 94;
Uint32 y = x.toUint32(); ///Pseudocode
```

Comment: flutter has only [int](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int-class.html) class, there is no `Uint32` class - you mean `Uint32List` or `Uint32Buffer` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart doesn't have a unsigned integers.

You can however use a `BigInt` and use [toUnsigned(32)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/BigInt/toUnsigned.html) after each operation you do to it.